# How to make AJAX responseText Convert to JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

```
var signal=jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://###/user/checkcaslogin.aspx",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
    }
});
```

[image: Object structure]

I want to Convert `responseText`into a JSON object, I have tried JSON.parse() but

[image: Syntax error]

and `typeof signal.responseText //String`

Comment: Have you tried logging `data`?

Comment: data will be an Object, if you want to make JSON out of it, you need to `JSON.stringify(data);` - However, I suspect you actually **don't** want to work with JSON, as it's a string, and you can't really do much with a string

Comment: I had tried `console.log(data)` but  nothing

Comment: Quote error messages, don't post pictures of them. Provide a [mcve] not just a fragment of code (which doesn't appear to relate to the other bits of code or the error messages at all).

Comment: Since you said `dataType: 'json'`, jQuery parses the JSON automatically. You don't need to call `JSON.parse()` yourself.

Comment: the object you posted a picture of ... that's not `data`, that's `signal`, right?

Comment: hmm ... `{"code": 00}` is invalid JSON ... you need to fix the server side my friend

Answer (score 6):

If you want to parse the response text as JSON, first you have to **send JSON in the response**.

[JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/) is a useful tool for debugging this sort of thing.

This is not valid JSON:

```
{ "code": 00 }
```

The Number data type in JSON cannot begin with a double zero.

[image: Numbers in JSON]

---

After you fix the response, the `success` function will fire, and `data` will be the result of parsing the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` parameter is already an object, so you can just use it as object. If you prefer to get the JSON string for whatever reason, use `JSON.stringify(data)` to get the JSON string.

Comment: Or don't specify `dataType: 'json'`, and then `data` will be the original JSON string.

Comment: @Barmar — No. If you don't specify the `dataType` then jQuery will infer it from the `Content-Type` response header.